# キーエンス製のセンサとpythonを使ったASCIIのやり取り

Tags: python

キーエンス製のセンサで、ASCIIのやり取りをすることになっています。
仕様書には、一例としてこのようなデータを送信すると正常に受信するとありました。

```
SR,06,101CRLF（ASCII）
0x53, 0x52, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x31, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x30, 0x31, 0x0D, 0x0A（16進数）
```

この一例をpythonのコードで作成し、送信しましたが、信号は送信されているのですが、アラーム表示が出て、正常に受信されていないようです。
ASCIIコードの送信を今回始めてpythonで書きました。コードにおかしいところがあるでしょうか？どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

```
import serial
import time
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0', 9600)

senddata = [0x53, 0x52, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x31, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x30, 0x31, 0x0D, 0x0A]
send_binary = bytes(senddata)

ser.write(send_binary)
ser.close()
```

Comment: 5個目(`6`)のデータが0x36ではなく0x31になっているのと、最後から2つ目のデータがCR(0x0D)ではなく0x00になっているからでは？

Comment: kunif  様
ありがとうございます！後ろから2つの目のデータを0x0Dにして　
senddata = [0x53, 0x52, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x31, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x30, 0x31, 0x0D, 0x0A]　
で送信をかけましたがまだ、アラーム表示が出ました。

Comment: まだ5個目(`6`)のデータが0x31になっているのが残っていますよ。それを0x36にしてみてください。

Comment: kunif 　様
ありがとうございます！これで　senddata = [0x53, 0x52, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x36, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x30, 0x31, 0x0D, 0x0A]　送信してみましたが駄目でした。すみません！

Comment: 例えばRS232Cのラインモニタとかを間に入れて、PuTTYとかTeraTermとか手動のターミナルソフトで通信したのと、通るデータを比べてみてはどうでしょう？ 後は、質問時の簡略化のためでしょうか、`read()`して表示する処理が無く送信直後に`close()`していますが、`read`処理側で問題が発生しているとかありませんか？

Comment: kunif 　様
ありがとうございます！実は、これはラズパイのTXとRXからセンサーと通信をやろうとしているのですが、モニターを挟むやり方を調べて試してみます！（＞＜　
また、closeなのですが、理解半ばで書いていました。write直後に「line = ser.readline()」も入れたりいろいろしていたのですが、どれもアラームが出てしまいました・・・

Comment: キーエンスのマニュアルを参照すると、`SR,06,...` の `06` は `Specify the ID number assigned to the target sensor amplifier using two digits` と記載されています。お使いのセンサーID は `06` なのでしょうか？

Comment: metropolis　様
ありがとうございます！センサーは2つなので「00」か「01」なので、この部分を「00」か[01」で表現したのですが、それでもだめでした・・・

Comment: 英語版でのマルチポスト[ASCII exchange using python with KEYENCE sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67605512/9014308)があり、そのコメントで少し進展があるようですが、双方の内容を同等に更新するようにしてください。その内容を考えると、最初から2台接続するのはいったんやめて、まず1台だけ接続して動作確認した方が良いと思われます。

Comment: kunif 　様　度々ありがとうございます！英語版の件、承知いたしました。まだ、実はそんなに進展がない状態です。厚かましいお願いで本当に申し訳ないのですが、通るデータの確認方法で何かおすすめの記事をご紹介いただけると幸いです。

Comment: あまり進展が無いなら、例えばRaspberry PiではなくPCと直接接続して何かのターミナルソフトで通信するとかの、ほとんど追加コストの掛からない全く別の方法で動作確認してみて、現在の現象との差を見つけると言ったことが考えられます。PCとの接続ならラインモニタを間に挟んだりするのは簡単でしょう。あるいはソフトウェアによるトレースやアナライズツール(だいたい有償でしょうが)なども使えるでしょう。

Comment: kunif 様　ご丁寧にありがとうございます！アナライズツールを使って一度、信号を確かめてみます。もし何かわかれば、コメントいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

なんでASCIIという指定なのにバイナリで送ろうとしてるのかよくわかりませんが、

> senddata = [0x53, 0x52, 0x2C, 0x30, 0x31, 0x2C, 0x31, 0x30, 0x31, 0x00, 0x0A]

CRのコードの位置に0x00が入ってしまってますよ

Comment: y_waiwai 様
ありがとうございます！すみません、「0x00」はペーストミスです。今編集しました。
「0x0D」で送信しているのですが、状況は同じです。紛らわしくてすみません。
というよりも、私は大きな勘違いしているのでしょうか？ASCIIで交信する場合でもバイナリーで送受信して受信側でASCII解釈と思っていたのですが、それは違うのでしょうか？

Comment: senddata = "SR,06,101\r\n"
send_binary = senddata.encode() でいいんじゃ

Comment: PySerialの[write(data)](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#serial.Serial.write)仕様で、Python3系では文字列を直接指定出来ないので、バイナリのリストを作るのは効率は悪いですが間違いでは無いですね。まあ@y_waiwaiさんのコメントのように`.encode()`で`bytes`に変換する方法でも良いですが、一番簡単なのは頭に[バイトオブジェクト](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects)を示す`b`を付けることですね。そうすれば`ser.write(b'SR,06,101\r\n')`と言う風に直接書けます。[Python Serial write function not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22835551/9014308), [pySerial write() won't take my string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22275079/9014308)

Comment: y_waiwai　様、kunif　様　ありがとうございます！すごく参考になりました！また、本題の方なのですが、モニターを挟んで通信の流れを監視したところ、ハード側を起動した直後からノイズみたいな信号が流れており、これがシリアル通信に影響していたのかもしれません。ハードを一度別入れ替えてみてうまくいくか試してみます。うまくいけばまたコメントいたします。

Comment: y_waiwai　様、kunif　様　ありがとうございました。ハードウェア側に問題がありました。交換したら無事に動きました。このコードで問題がなかったみたいです。コメントをいただき本当に感謝しています。